# Slow app load because dotnet.wasm not cached for AOT and InterpreterAOT builds

Tags: uno-platform

I'm trying to improve the load time performance of my Uno Platform WASM app.  It's hosted on an IIS/10.0 Server.  When I do a browser reload on page that hosts a `<WasmShellMonoRuntimeExecutionMode>Interpreter</WasmShellMonoRuntimeExecutionMode>` build of this app, I can see in the browser's network log that it's pulling `dotnet.wasm` from the browser's cache:

[image: Interpreted dotnet.wasm Reload]

However, when I do a browser reload on page that hosts a `<WasmShellMonoRuntimeExecutionMode>InterpreterAndAOT</WasmShellMonoRuntimeExecutionMode>` or `<WasmShellMonoRuntimeExecutionMode>FullAOT</WasmShellMonoRuntimeExecutionMode>` build, it always pulls the file from the server:

[image]

I've tried this on Chrome, Edge, Edge Beta, FireFox, and Opera - all with the same result.

All builds have the same `web.config` file in their root directory.

**EDIT 1**: The `web.config` file is the one from Uno Template (unmodified).

**EDIT 2**: I should also note that since initially posting this question I found that it appears `web.config` is working with IIS Express and Azure Web App Service (the compressed versions of the app files are being served AND `dotnet.wasm` is cached by the browser) - but not IIS Server on a Windows 10 Server (the compressed versions of the app files are NOT being served AND `dotnet.wasm` is NOT being cached by the browser).

Is there something I'm missing in my build configuration that's triggering this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The Uno Platform app template provides [a web.config file](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/9ffc959f45d7a349df20fb45827eb74e8072695a/src/SolutionTemplate/UnoSolutionTemplate/Wasm/wwwroot/web.config) that enables compression, and avoids this kind of issues.

That web.config file uses the [IIS URL rewriting module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) and brotli/gzip compression to make assets download a lot faster.

Comment: Thank you, Jerome for the quick response.  Two notes:  (1)  The `web.config` file is the one from Uno Template (unmodified).  (2) It appears `web.config` is working with IIS Express and Azure Web App Service - Just not IIS Server on a Windows 10 Server.